# Functions that takes and returns vector in R

Tags: r, function

I want to create a function to help me convert a vector containing different values of Ghanaian Cedi to Hungarian Forint  (1 cedi = 57.06 forint). My function name is `Currency`; such that if I give the function a vector `[1,2,3,4]`,where1,2,3,4 represents cedi, the function will return me `Currency(1)`, `Currency(2)`, `Currency(3)` ,`Currency(4)`, which are forints.

I was thinking of using loop to create my function. Before that, I would like to know if there's any easier way to separate the vector?

Comment: Do you need `1:4 * 57.06` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vectors are a native data type in R. A numeric value is actually a numeric vector with one element as far as R is concerned.

In other words, R works directly with vectors making loops or `apply` functions rarely useful for trivial operations. Multiplying by a constant is a standard vector operation.

The function below handles a vector just fine:

```
convert_currency <- function(cedi) {
  cedi * 57.06
}

convert_currency(1:4)
#> [1]  57.06 114.12 171.18 228.24
```